# Наследование класса QGraphicsItem. Неккоректная работа

Tags: c++, qt

Данный класс должен нарисовать квадрат, а по нажатию левой кнопки мышки - эллипс. Квадрат рисует, но по нажатию на него ничего не происходит.

Не могу понять причины.

Класс:

```
#ifndef BUBBLE_H
#define BUBBLE_H

#include <QPainter>
#include <QGraphicsItem>

class bubble : public QGraphicsEllipseItem
{
private:
    int posX, posY, width, height;
    bool pressed;
public:
    bubble(int x, int y, int w, int h);
    QRectF boundingRect() const;
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);

protected:
    virtual void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
    virtual void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
};

#endif // BUBBLE_H
```

Методы:

```
#include <bubble.h>

bubble::bubble(int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
    pressed = false;

    posX = x;
    posY = y;
    width = w;
    height = h;
}

QRectF bubble::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRectF(posX, posY, width, height);
}

void bubble::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    QRectF rect = boundingRect();
    painter->setBrush(Qt::red);

    if(pressed) 
        painter->drawEllipse(rect);
    else 
        painter->drawRect(rect);
}

void bubble::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    pressed = true;
    update();
    QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent(event);
}

void bubble::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    pressed = false;
    update();
    QGraphicsItem::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

У вас при нажатии кнопки мыши вызывается сначала `mousePressEvent`, а при отпускании `mouseReleaseEvent`. Вот и получается, что `pressed` все время `false`.
Попробуйте изменить `mouseReleaseEvent` так:

```
void bubble::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event){
    if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton){
        pressed = !pressed;
        update();
    }
    QGraphicsItem::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
}
```

А `mousePressEvent` уберите совсем